# How to combine basename and filepath into a specialized list - R?

Tags: r, list

I have a folder containing a variety of .img files.  I can list all of the files in the folder using the following method:

```
files = "C:/imagery/Landsat"

rlist=list.files(path = files, pattern="img$", full.names=TRUE) 

> rlist
[1] "C:/imagery/Landsat/image1.img"
[2] "C:/imagery/Landsat/image2.img"
[3] "C:/imagery/Landsat/image3.img"
```

I know how to extract the basename from the file paths, using the following approach:

```
> strsplit(basename(rlist[1]), '\\.')[[1]][1]
[1] "image1"
```

However, I am in need of a special list following this format:

```
rlist2 = list(image1 = "C:/imagery/Landsat/image1.img",
              image2 = "C:/imagery/Landsat/image2.img",
              image3 = "C:/imagery/Landsat/image3.img")
```

How should I put these disjointed pieces together to form the specialized list in `rlist2`?

Comment: The function `setNames` may be what you’re after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to assign names to the entries in your vector (each entry will get the corresponding file name), as follows:

```
> library(tools)
> names(rlist) <- basename(file_path_sans_ext(rlist))
```

Then, to get a list in the format that you specified, you can simply do:

```
rlist2 <- as.list(rlist)
```

This is the output:

```
> rlist2

$image1
[1] "C:/imagery/Landsat/image1.img"

$image2
[1] "C:/imagery/Landsat/image2.img"

$image3
[1] "C:/imagery/Landsat/image3.img"
```

And you can access individual entries in the list, as follows:

```
> rlist2$image1
[1] "C:/imagery/Landsat/image1.img"
```

You can read more about the `as.list` function and its behavior [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/list.html).